# TensorFlow: InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow and need to implement a deep neural network for a regression task. I assume there are no such sample codes on the internet where regression is performed using deep neural network (at least I could not find any. Please post any helpful link, if available). So, I have tried to merge the tutorials on deep neural networks for classification and regression together for my purpose. As expected, I am bombarded with errors. The error message reads:

```
InvalidArgumentError: In[0] is not a matrix
 [[Node: MatMul_35 = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_36_0, Variable_72/read)]]
```

The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_nodes_hl1 = 100
n_nodes_hl2 = 100

batch_size = 100

n_input = 1;
n_output = 1;
learning_rate = 0.01

train_X = numpy.asarray([3.3,4.4,5.5,6.71,6.93,4.168,9.779,6.182,7.59,2.167,
                 7.042,10.791,5.313,7.997,5.654,9.27,3.1])
train_Y = numpy.asarray([1.7,2.76,2.09,3.19,1.694,1.573,3.366,2.596,2.53,1.221,
                 2.827,3.465,1.65,2.904,2.42,2.94,1.3])

x = tf.placeholder('float')
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
   hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

   hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

   l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
   l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

   l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
   l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

   output = tf.reduce_sum(l2)

   return output

def train_neural_network(x):
   prediction = neural_network_model(x)
   cost = tf.square(y - prediction)

   optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

   hm_epochs = 5
   with tf.Session() as sess:

      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

      for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
         epoch_loss = 0
         for (X, Y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
             _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})
             epoch_loss += c

         print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

      plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, 'ro', label='Original data')
      plt.plot(train_X, prediction, label='Fitted line')
      plt.legend()
      plt.show()

      test_X = numpy.asarray([6.83, 4.668, 8.9, 7.91, 5.7, 8.7, 3.1, 2.1])
      test_Y = numpy.asarray([1.84, 2.273, 3.2, 2.831, 2.92, 3.24, 1.35, 1.03])
      print("Testing Data")

      correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
      print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_X, y:test_Y}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

As far I guess there is an issue with the dimensions of the hidden layer weights and/or biases (I may be wrong).

Side note: Here I have just tried to make a simple model of my project where the training and testing data points have been taken from the internet examples. My actual data would be pixel values of several images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Change this line (working for me) :**

1. Inputs to matmul() functions should be a matrix - you are feeding a value.

   ```
   _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: [[X]], y: [[Y]]})
   ```

Output:

```
('Epoch', 0, 'completed out of', 5, 'loss:', array([[  1.20472407e+14]], dtype=float32))
('Epoch', 1, 'completed out of', 5, 'loss:', array([[ 6.82631159]], dtype=float32))
('Epoch', 2, 'completed out of', 5, 'loss:', array([[ 8.83840561]], dtype=float32))
('Epoch', 3, 'completed out of', 5, 'loss:', array([[ 8.00222397]], dtype=float32))
('Epoch', 4, 'completed out of', 5, 'loss:', array([[ 7.6564579]], dtype=float32))
```

Hope this helps !

**Comment:** This is not a good example to explore if you're going to work 
with images.

Comment: I meant, you should try using CNNs. Any specific reason you want to estimate error not depth image ? There are few publications that experimented with estimating depth from a single image. For example : http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Liu_Deep_Convolutional_Neural_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it works!! With regard to my project, I have a set of images and corresponding error images (error between actual depth image, using time of flight camera, and estimated depth image, calculated using stereo cameras). I have to model the error in the estimated depth pixel values. I was thinking to use the image pixels to be the input(X) and the corresponding error pixel values to be the output(Y) to train the neural network. I am an absolute newbie to TensorFlow. Considering your comment, can you think of a better approach to this problem? Please tell me if you need more info

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am already done with estimating the depth images using stereo setup. I also have the reference depth values. Now I have to model the errors between the estimated values and ground truth.

Comment: I see. You can follow similar techniques(CNN) to do your task then. Anyways, good to know that my answer worked for you.